# Are conduits run along floors code permitted?

Tags: electrical, woodworking

I'm running 240v outlets in my garage for several woodworking machines. To keep the conduits out of sight, I'd like to run them 4-6" off the floor along the bottom of the wall.

Is this allowable under NEC?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't be a problem. If the garage has a habit of filling with water, you'll need to use conduit and conductors rated for wet locations. Otherwise I can't think of any problems.

You'll have to use conduit that can be subject to physical damage.

To be sure, contact your local building department.